# Is it possible to use cuda or opengl in a container without passthrough the physical gpu?

Tags: drivers, nvidia-graphics-card, kernel, cuda

After googling how to run cuda in a container, I am confused why most articles requires "passthrough" the gpu to the container: the container does not have own kernel, how does the kernel mode driver run in it?

My idea is to install the kernel mode driver on the host, and user mode driver and cuda toolkit inside the container and contact through syscall. Is it possible?